# How to implement an English dictionary in Java?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dictionary of English Words for a J2ME app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572780/dictionary-of-english-words-for-a-j2me-app)

I am working on a project that needs to check the strength of a password based on the existence of an English word in the dictionary. My problem is to know whether there is any Java API for an English dictionary. If not what hints can help me to implement such dictionary ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572780/dictionary-of-english-words-for-a-j2me-app

There are many.

Comment: Are you interested in finding a corpus (a list of words and definitions) or in data structures (how to store the contents of the dictionary) ?

Comment: I am interested in finding a list of English word! BTW Russell posted below a link to a file that contains many English words.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you just need to know if a word exists in English, just get a text file containing all English words and read it in to a `HashSet`.

For example:

http://code.google.com/p/dotnetperls-controls/downloads/detail?name=enable1.txt

Comment: I got the text file from the link provided but i wonder how i should read that in to a HashSet! Is a HashSet similar to  a Hashtable or dictionary object ? Thx

Comment: Read the file line by line with a `BufferedReader` and add each line to the set until you reach the end of the file.

Comment: Oh i get the idea! Thanx a lot !!

Comment: @RussellZahniser, link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Look for Natural Language Processing libraries in Java. There a bunch of them out there.